# Используя || вывести сообщение об ошибке если пользователь не введет возраст или нажмет отмену

Tags: javascript

Используя || вывести сообщение об ошибке если пользователь не введет возраст или нажмет отмену. Через if или switch - легко, а через или - не пойму((

```
function error(){alert("Error!");}
function displayDate(age){
    var date = new Date();
 alert(`You year of birdth ${date.getFullYear() - age}`);
}
var age = Number(prompt("How are you old?"));
age==""||age==null||error();
displayDate(age);
// if(age==""||age==null){
//     alert("Error!");
// }
// else{
//     var date = new Date();
// alert(`You year of birdth ${date.getFullYear() - age}`);
// }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем вот решение:

```js
function error() {
   return'Error!';
}
var age = Number(prompt("How are you old?")) || error();
console.log(age);
```

Все очень просто, если вы введете в `prompt` число, то вернет число, в случае отмены, ввода строки, пустоты, вернет то, что находится в `error()`.

Answer (score 0):

Странная задача конечно, как вариант можно сделать так :

```js
const error = () => console.log("Error!")

const displayDate = age => console.log(`You year of birdth ${new Date().getFullYear() - age}`)

const doIt = () => {
  const age = +prompt("How are you old?")
  age && displayDate(age) || !age && error()
}

doIt()
```

Comment: Что означает !age?

Comment: @Domosed_007 вот, почитайте : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B

Answer (score 0):

Логическое ИЛИ в классическом программировании работает следующим образом: "если хотя бы один из аргументов true, то возвращает true, иначе – false". В JavaScript это не совсем так. Если значение не логического типа – то оно к нему приводится в целях вычислений. Например, число 1 будет воспринято как true, а 0 – как false. JavaScript вычисляет несколько ИЛИ слева направо. При этом, чтобы экономить ресурсы, используется так называемый «короткий цикл вычисления».

Допустим, вычисляются несколько ИЛИ подряд: a || b || c || .... Если первый аргумент – true, то результат заведомо будет true (хотя бы одно из значений – true), и остальные значения игнорируются.

Это особенно заметно, когда выражение, переданное в качестве второго аргумента, имеет сторонний эффект – например, присваивает переменную. При запуске примера ниже присвоение x не произойдёт:

```
var x;

true || (x = 1);

alert(x); // undefined, x не присвоен
```

…А в примере ниже первый аргумент – false, так что ИЛИ попытается вычислить второй, запустив тем самым присваивание:

```
var x;

false || (x = 1);

alert(x); // 1
```

Я думаю, вы должны вывести сообщение об ошибке тогда, когда 
`age == undefined`
а не null.
А Ваш запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
undefined == age || error();
```

Comment: || возвращает не false или true, а первый операнд, который может быть приведён к true либо последний. В false или true его преобразовывает if, например.